# How can I make these images center aligned?

Tags: css

I want to make the grey images center aligned. Please guide me how can I do this.
Here is what I have tried:

```
<div id="responsivearea" style="margin-top: 50px;">
   <div class="img-center">
      <img style="clear:none;" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-2707" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/visa-logo2-150x150.jpg" alt="visa logo" width="150" height="150" />
      <img style="clear:none;" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-2705" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/nethope-logo1-150x150.jpg" alt="nethope logo" width="150" height="150" /> 
      <img style="clear:none;" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-2704"  src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/ILO-logo1-150x150.jpg" alt="ILO logo" width="150" height="150" />
   </div>
</div>
```

[Here](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan) is the site.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
.img-center{text-align: center;}
```

Comment: I also need to make them horizontally aligned.

Comment: Yes, this does. As you have images only inside img-center.

Comment: I think he means vertically aligned. Does this help, @ShenXu? http://jsfiddle.net/n6522/4/

Comment: @KennyJohnson: I need horizontal aligned images.

Answer (score 0):

Set margin to auto. The browser will align the images to center for you

```
img {
    margin: auto;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested already, magin auto... using your existing img-center class

```
.img-center{
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align:middle; /* If you mean vertically aligned  */
}
```

text-align can work but is a little funny in cross browser support...

margin auto generally does the job and should work

otherwise just wrap them with center tags, while people may frown upon using center tags..THEY WORK CROSS BROWSER!! so they will NOT fail!

Otherwise, if you mean the footer images/logos on the site.. They are in a P tag without any class.. You can simply apply a text-align:center: to that p tag.